# lost all data with yum erase yum-plugin-priorities

Tags: amazon-web-services, yum

I was trying to install phpmyadmin on amazonlinux ec2 but i was getting this error: "packages excluded due to repository priority protections"

so end up trying `sudo running yum erase yum-plugin-priorities` to disable plugin priorities so i could get that package.

After that i had no sudo access. And then I couldn't log in.

So I decided to "stop" and "start" the instance

So then i could log in... but everything is gone. i didnt back up :(

**stopping ec2 should not have killed the ebs**

Is there anyway to get my data back?

Comment: Are you sure it was an EBS backed instance? Did you accidentally terminate it instead of stopping it?

Comment: yes im sure i pressed stop. however it didnt appear to go smoothly.

Comment: The command уоu were looking for maybe was `yum update --disableplugin=priorities`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that this was actually a Beanstalk Application. I was treating it as if it was regular EC2 instance. That is what messed up when trying to install things, and when stopping it in the EC2 menu.